# Показать и скрыть элементы на странице с localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеем маркированный список и блоки разбросанные на странице. При клике на пункт списка открывается блок с выбранным классом, а другой становится не активным. В общем-то по коду все будет понятно.

Необходимо через localStoragе сделать проверку элементов с классом "active". Чтоб при перезагрузке страниц, результат выбранный пользователем сохранялся.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    $(".sh-list li").click(function() {
      $(".sh-list li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
    });

    $('.sh-list li').on('click',function(e) {
      $('.sh-cont').removeClass('active');
    });
  
    $('.sh-list li').on('click',function(e) {
      if ($(this).hasClass('b1')) {
        $('.sh-cont.b1').addClass('active');
      }
      else if($(this).hasClass('b2')) {
        $('.sh-cont.b2').addClass('active');
      }
      else if($(this).hasClass('b3')) {
        $('.sh-cont.b3').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  
});
```

```css
.sh-list li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sh-list li.active {
  color: red;
}
.sh-cont {
  display: none;
}
.sh-cont.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sh-list">
  <li class="b1 active">Block 1</li>
  <li class="b2">Block 2</li>
  <li class="b3">Block 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="sh-cont b1 active">text 1</div>
<div class="sh-cont b2">text 2</div>
<div class="sh-cont b3">text 3</div>
```

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 2):

В простом случае, если у элементов списка будет только один класс, можно по нему и определять выбранный, а также сохранять этот класс в localStorage и использовать его при загрузке

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sh-list li").click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) return;
    $(".sh-list li.active, .sh-cont.active").add('.' + this.className).toggleClass('active');
    //localStorage["selected"] = '.' + this.className;
  });
  /*
  if (localStorage["selected"]) {
    $(localStorage["selected"]).addClass('active');
  }
  */
});
```

```css
.sh-list li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sh-list li.active {
  color: red;
}
.sh-cont {
  display: none;
}
.sh-cont.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sh-list">
  <li class="b1 active">Block 1</li>
  <li class="b2">Block 2</li>
  <li class="b3">Block 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="sh-cont b1 active">text 1</div>
<div class="sh-cont b2">text 2</div>
<div class="sh-cont b3">text 3</div>
```

Но лучше убрать общую часть из класса, например в какой-нибудь `data-*` атрибут, например так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sh-list li").click(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) return;
    $(".sh-list li.active, .sh-cont.active").add(`[data-item="${$this.data('item')}"]`)
                                            .toggleClass('active');
    //localStorage["selected"] = $this.data('item');
  });
  /*
  if (localStorage["selected"]) {
    $(`[data-item="${localStorage["selected"]}"]`).addClass('active');
  }
  */
});
```

```css
.sh-list li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sh-list li.active {
  color: red;
}
.sh-cont {
  display: none;
}
.sh-cont.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="sh-list">
  <li data-item="b1" class="b1 active">Block 1</li>
  <li data-item="b2" class="b2">Block 2</li>
  <li data-item="b3" class="b3">Block 3</li>
</ul>

<div data-item="b1" class="sh-cont b1 active">text 1</div>
<div data-item="b2" class="sh-cont b2">text 2</div>
<div data-item="b3" class="sh-cont b3">text 3</div>
```

Comment: Интересные решения. Спасибо за помощь. Есть ли объективные причины заменить мой вариант одним из ваших? Голос все равно отдам за ваш пост.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, стоит разобраться что происходит в моем коде и что в твоем. В итоге все сведется почти к одному и тому же

Comment: Вот и я смотрю, что результат один и тот же, просто разная подача. Еще раз спасибо за участие.

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашлось. Даже в более удобном виде, исключив условия из скрипта и, конечно же, с подгрузкой данных после обновления страницы.

Тут можно потестировать: http://codepen.io/pen/VKvmrY

Сам скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".sh-list li").each(function(){
      $(this).click(function(){
        localStorage.selectedTab = $(this).index() + 1;
        tabeId = $(this).attr('id');
        $(".sh-list li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".sh-cont").addClass("hide");
        $("#"+tabeId+"-1").removeClass("hide")   
        return false;     
      });
    });  

    if (localStorage.selectedTab) {
      $(".sh-list li:eq(" + (localStorage.selectedTab - 1) + ")").click();
    }
});
```

Немного подправлена разметка:

```
<ul class="sh-list">
  <li class="active" id="b1">Block 1</li>
  <li id="b2">Block 2</li>
  <li id="b3">Block 3</li>
</ul>

<div class="sh-cont" id="b1-1">text 1</div>
<div class="sh-cont" id="b2-1">text 2</div>
<div class="sh-cont" id="b3-1">text 3</div>
```

И стили:

```
.sh-list li {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.sh-list li.active {
  color: red;
}
.hide { display: none; }
```

Comment: а в чем смысл при сохранении добавлять 1 к индексу, а при загрузке вычитать?

Comment: .index() используйется для получения позиции элемента списка. И по умолчанию он возвращает 0 для первого пункта. Поэтому я добавляю единицу, чтоб результат их index возвращался не с 0,1,2,3... , а с 1,2,3...